# How to mock os.path.join using mockito

Tags: python, python-2.7, mockito, pytest, python-unittest

I tried mocking `mock.patch('os.path.join',lambda str:'test.txt')`.

I observed the below error:

```
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 178, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 215, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 617, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 222, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 216, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 201, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 77, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     _reraise(*ex)  # noqa
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 236, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 617, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 222, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 216, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 201, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 77, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     _reraise(*ex)  # noqa
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 64, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 79, in runtestprotocol
INTERNALERROR>     reports.append(call_and_report(item, "call", log))
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 161, in call_and_report
INTERNALERROR>     report = hook.pytest_runtest_makereport(item=item, call=call)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 617, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self, self._nonwrappers + self._wrappers, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 222, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/__init__.py", line 216, in <lambda>
INTERNALERROR>     firstresult=hook.spec_opts.get('firstresult'),
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 196, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     gen.send(outcome)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/skipping.py", line 123, in pytest_runtest_makereport
INTERNALERROR>     rep = outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 77, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     _reraise(*ex)  # noqa
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pluggy/callers.py", line 180, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 328, in pytest_runtest_makereport
INTERNALERROR>     longrepr = item.repr_failure(excinfo)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 672, in repr_failure
INTERNALERROR>     return self._repr_failure_py(excinfo, style=style)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/python.py", line 665, in _repr_failure_py
INTERNALERROR>     return super(FunctionMixin, self)._repr_failure_py(excinfo, style=style)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/nodes.py", line 295, in _repr_failure_py
INTERNALERROR>     tbfilter=tbfilter,
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 472, in getrepr
INTERNALERROR>     return fmt.repr_excinfo(self)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 702, in repr_excinfo
INTERNALERROR>     reprtraceback = self.repr_traceback(excinfo)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 659, in repr_traceback
INTERNALERROR>     reprentry = self.repr_traceback_entry(entry, einfo)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 618, in repr_traceback_entry
INTERNALERROR>     reprargs = self.repr_args(entry) if not short else None
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 539, in repr_args
INTERNALERROR>     args.append((argname, self._saferepr(argvalue)))
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/_code/code.py", line 533, in _saferepr
INTERNALERROR>     return py.io.saferepr(obj)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_vendored_packages/apipkg.py", line 148, in __makeattr
INTERNALERROR>     result = importobj(modpath, attrname)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py/_vendored_packages/apipkg.py", line 69, in importobj
INTERNALERROR>     module = __import__(modpath, None, None, ['__doc__'])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 97, in find_module
INTERNALERROR>     fn = os.path.join(pth, name.rpartition(".")[2] + ".py")
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockito/mocking.py", line 88, in new_mocked_method
INTERNALERROR>     self, method_name, *args, **kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockito/mocking.py", line 44, in remembered_invocation_builder
INTERNALERROR>     return invoc(*args, **kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockito/invocation.py", line 164, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     *params, **named_params)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockito/invocation.py", line 293, in answer_first
INTERNALERROR>     return self.answers.answer(*args, **kwargs)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockito/invocation.py", line 402, in answer
INTERNALERROR>     return a(*args, **kwargs)
INTERNALERROR> TypeError: <lambda>() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Any help?

Comment: I have to ask: why do you need to mock a trivial string-manipulation helper function?

Comment: I had to go through tat function which as this piece of line and i need to mock this in order to get the file where i want

Answer (score 1):

`os.path.join` takes one or more arguments, but your replacement (`lambda str:'test.txt'`) only takes one. Could that be the cause of the error?

If so, you could try `lambda s, *args: "test.txt"` instead.

Comment: `os.path.join` takes one or more arguments. `os.path.join("one_thing")` is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the typical mockito usage here would be `when(os.path).join(...).thenReturn('one_thing')`. The literal `...` (Ellipsis) I'm using here is valid in Python3.

For Python 2.7, you could

`from mockito import args
when(os.path).join(*args).thenReturn('one_thing')`